# How to copy or sync music on iphone 3gs on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to copy music to/on my iPhone 3gs. I already installed the actual mobile device, but neither Rhythmbox nor gmusicbrowser show my phone. Only on Gigolo I can see it, and transfer data, but the music I copy is not working on my phone.

On Amarok I get at least this information:

```
termined mount-point path to /tmp/kde-cafer/amarok/imobiledevice_uuid_882ba1378fe4eb76e98ad6582dcad031c2247664
calling `ifuse "-u" "882ba1378fe4eb76e98ad6582dcad031c2247664" "-ofsname=afc://882ba1378fe4eb76e98ad6582dcad031c2247664" "/tmp/kde-cafer/amarok/imobiledevice_uuid_882ba1378fe4eb76e98ad6582dcad031c2247664"` with timeout of 10s
command failed to start within timeout
Failed to mount iPhone on /tmp/kde-cafer/amarok/imobiledevice_uuid_882ba1378fe4eb76e98ad6582dcad031c2247664
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple saves music files using a proprietary hash.  Rhythmbox used to support this but Apple changed the hash a little while ago and I found while I could transfer the music files to my i device - the device would not play them.

I could not find a solution to the re-hashed files.

I had to revert to the abomination that is iTunes.

Comment: i also tried with banshee, it seems to work at first, music is copying and transfering, but when i look at my phone, there is no datatransfer. do i understand you right, that i have to sync it with i tunes on an other PC/Mac?
thanks Dave

Comment: Unfortunately that is what it looks like unless someone can reverse engineer Apple's hash.  I think Rythmbox worked up until iPod version 4 or so then the hash changed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I add music to my iPhone 5 is through EZMP3
[EZMP3 Player on the App Store on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ezmp3-player/id449810822?mt=8)
I end up dragging the songs I want on the phone from my mp3 directory on the computer, but they get there and play.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible with a VM on Virtualbox or VMware. It's a shame that iTunes only supports Mac and Window$.